# How to find formula for check digit?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that:

603479187241 has check digit 27

603479187242 has check digit 75

603473992393 has check digit 70

Is there a mathematical way to get the check digit formula?
I have tried some of the known formulas using Mod 10, GS1, GTIN but none worked. Thanks.

Comment: Hash functions are usually rather hard to track backwards. There are so horribly many different ways to produce a number from a sequence of digits.

Comment: @mathreadler, I was hoping that someone with several check-digit calculators could figure it out. Thx.